# Como listar e monitorar os app's que estão instaladas e/ou em uso?

Tags: android

Em um aparelho Android, onde estão executando muitos app's, gostaria de possibilitar uma interface onde o usuário poderá ver quais app's instalados e os que estão rodando no momento atual, sendo possível iniciar, pausar e desinstalar um app.

1. Por onde devo começo?
2. Quais classes, métodos ou interfaces responsáveis por listar os app's afim de monitorá-las?

Comment: O Android é um sistema que preza muito pela estabilidade e segurança, e por isso a possibilidade de fechar aplicativo já pode ser descartada, o maximo que você pode é fechar background tasks (*Activity Manager*) pausar eu acho que não tem como se não pelo proprio usuario e iniciar você pode dar uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android acredito que uma refêrencia completa doque vc pode fazer é o Activity Manager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Comment: Ver apps instalados, pará-los e desinstalá-los dá pra fazer pela opção `Configurações > Aplicativos`. Fora isso, acho que só com um aparelho "rooteado" seria possível criar outro aplicativo para fazer o mesmo.

Comment: "O Android é um sistema que preza muito pela estabilidade e segurança" Não é minimamente verdade...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Conforme está [resposta no SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868834/1518921) o método deve chamado assim (`ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` está disponível apenas na API level 14):

   ```
   Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:org.PACOTE");
   Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
   startActivity(uninstallIntent);
   ```
2. (Até o API Level 20) Para listar os aplicativos que estão rodando (ou foram executados recentemente), conforme está [resposta do SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8091379/1518921) o código deve ser algo como:

   ```
   final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

   for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)  {
       Log.d("Aplicativo executado", "Aplicativo: " + recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString() + "\t\t ID: " + recentTasks.get(i).id);
   }
   ```
3. Para API Level 21 use [`getAppTasks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks%28%29)

Comment: O método [`getRunningTasks(int maxNum)`, foi depreciado na API level 21 (LOLLIPOP)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)), por questões de segurança, pela possibilidade de vazar informações pessoais a aplicativos de terceiros. (Se for utilizar este método esteja consciente que ela não será suportada para futuras versões Android).

Comment: @Fernando Obrigado, editei a resposta

Answer (score -1):

Faz parte do Android System, referente a Java Lang:veja esse link que fala sobre os metodos, interfaces...:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html.
Clique [aqui](http://www.portalandroid.org/comunidade/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3466) para ver um exemplo.

Comment: [esse link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42) fala sobre respostas que contenham basicamente links, seria legal dar uma olhada nele, no [meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) tem muitas coisas que podem nos auxiliar para deixar o SOpt cada vez melhor